# How to add a cell style in the style of a datagrid?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a dictionary with a style for datagrids, I have this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}" x:Key="DataGridDefault">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="150"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>

    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

I would like to include the style of the row inside the style of the datagrid. The style of the row that I want is:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrush}"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

I have tried to added it in this way:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}" x:Key="DataGridDefault">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="150"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>

    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrush}"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

But it is not possible. The idea it is to set s style for the datagrid, that contains the style of the row, to avoid to have to set the both styles in each datagrid of the application, just set the style of the datagrid, to set both styles. But I don't know if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `Setter` for the `RowStyle` property and add the style there as `Value`.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}" x:Key="DataGridDefault">
   <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
   <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
   <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False" />
   <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
   <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="150" />
   <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
   <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
   <Setter Property="RowStyle">
      <Setter.Value>
         <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
               <MultiDataTrigger>
                  <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                     <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true" />
                  </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                  <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                     <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrush}" />
                  </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
               </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
   <Style.Resources>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
   </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Alternatively, if you want both styles to be separated, you could do this.

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow" x:Key="DataGridRowDefault">
   <Style.Triggers>
      <MultiDataTrigger>
         <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true" />
         </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
         <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrush}" />
         </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
      </MultiDataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}" x:Key="DataGridDefault">
   <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
   <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
   <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False" />
   <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
   <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="150" />
   <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
   <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
   <Setter Property="RowStyle" Value="{StaticResource DataGridRowDefault}"/>
   <Style.Resources>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
   </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```